# How to make sprite rotate around a certain circumference in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, rotation, game-development, phaser-framework

I'm remaking 8ball pool in Phaser for fun and am in the process of setting up the aiming of the cue/cueball. I currently have the cue rotating around the center point of the cueball on mouse movement:

```
create() {
    // Spawn in pool table
    this.setupTable();

    // Initialize cueball
    this.cueball = new Ball(this, 847, 400, 'ballsAndCue', '14ball.png', true);
    
    // Initialize cue
    this.cue = new Cue(this, 800, 400, 'ballsAndCue', 'cue.png', this.cueball);

    // Set cue rotation to follow cursor on cursor movement
    this.input.on('pointermove', function (pointer) {
        this.angle = Phaser.Math.Angle.BetweenPoints(this.cue, pointer);
        this.cue.rotation = this.angle;
    }, this);
}
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlpqp.gif)

However I want the cue to rotate around the whole cue ball. I've tried supplying `this.cue` to `Phaser.Actions.RotateAround()`/`Phaser.Actions.RotateAroundDistance()` but couldn't get them to work. Looking at Phaser 2, they had a pivot you could set but I'm not seeing anything similar other than `setOrigin()`, which I have already used to have the cue spin around the tip.

Cue class:

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';

export default class Cue extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    constructor(scene, x, y, spritesheet, sprite, cueball) {
        super(scene, x, y, spritesheet, sprite);
        scene.add.existing(this);
        this.setX(cueball.x);
        this.setY(cueball.y);
        this.setScale(0.7, 1);
        this.setOrigin(0, 0.5);
        
    }
}
```

How can I get it so the cue rotates around the circumference of the cueball?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Easy solution is, put the *cue* into a [phaser container](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Container.html) *(with the desired relative distance to the ball)* and use that container as a *"pivot"* and rotate it. You will have to set the containers position to the `x` and `y` coordinate of the *cueball*.

**Here a Demo showcasing the mentioned solution:**
*(With some extra "sweet" cue motion)*

> The demo doesn't use sprites, but it solution works in the same way with ***sprites and images***

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    }
}; 

function create () {
    let ball = this.add.circle(200, 90, 10, 0x6666ff);
    let pivot = this.add.container(200, 90);
    let cue = this.add.rectangle(10, 0, 200, 4, 0xffffff)
      .setOrigin(0, .5);
       
    pivot.add(cue);
    
   // the following two tweens are only to showcase the example
    this.tweens.add({
        targets: pivot,
        rotation: -Math.PI * 2,
        duration: 3000,
        repeat: -1
    });

   this.tweens.add({
        targets: cue,
        x:{
            from: 10,
            to: 80,
        },
        duration: 500,
        repeat: -1,
        yoyo: true
    });
 
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js">
</script>
```

> **Or** you could simply just add some transparent pixel *(with the desired offset)* to the image, **BUT** this is very limiting and only good if you don't need to move the *cue* in any other way then rotating it.